# youtube java client api set copyright on video upload

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, copyright-display

I am uploading videos to YouTube using the YouTube java client api. The most of it is working fine, but i've got still a problem with setting the copyright information.

```
VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();

YouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();

// adding different information to media group

MediaCopyright mediaCopyright = new MediaCopyright();
mediaCopyright.setContent("cc");
mediaCopyright.setUrl("http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/");
mediaGroup.setCopyright(mediaCopyright);

// upload video
```

I need help with this -.- Any ideas how i can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: the copyright information i set will be ignored... i cannot set the license to "creativeCommon"

Comment: Do you link `mediaCopyright` with `mediaGroup` or `newEntry` in some way? Seems like you are creating the object but not using it anywhere.

Comment: i'm creating a new MediaCopyright object and put the copyright information into it. and with mediaGroup.setCopyright(mediaCopyright) i'm putting the MediaCopyright object into the media group. is that the wrong way?